# setHidden with NSSlider doesn't work - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsslider

Hy guys, I'm new at ObjC and I'm still learning;
[sliderContrast setHidden:YES] (i also used slider.hidden = YES) doesn't make the slider invisible, instead it works fine with textfields. Do you know why?
I've also tried using property and synthesize but the result doesn't change

---Interface

```
@interface Controller : NSWindowController{
 
    IBOutlet NSTextField *labelContrast;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *valueContrast;
    IBOutlet NSSlider *sliderContrast;
}
- (IBAction)changeContrast:(id)sender;

@end
```

---Implementation

```
#import "Controller.h"

@interface Controller ()

@end


@implementation Controller

- (void)windowDidLoad {

    [super windowDidLoad];

    [labelContrast setHidden:YES];

    [valueContrast setHidden:YES];

    [sliderContrast setHidden:YES];

}

- (IBAction)changeContrast:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: Is the outlet connected? Unlike Swift where an exception is raised in Objective-C nothing happens

Comment: yes, i double checked

Comment: If this is supposed to be the initial appearance I recommend to set the `hidden` flags in Interface Builder.

Comment: how exactly? if i set the flag in the interface, xcode give me error

Comment: In Interface **Builder**, the place you connect the outlets.

Comment: thanks, i found it.

Comment: Why are you working with IBOutlet objects under `NSWindowController` in the first place?  Are they associated with `NSToolbar`?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare pointers for your objects but you don't allocate them yourself you can not set anything that is not there. Your `setHidden:` method calls end up in local void aka nowhere.

#### programmatically

If you go the coding way you would declare, allocate and initiate first. With

```
labelContrast = [NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(x,y,w,h)];
```

before you call other methods of the object class (Or similar init methods).
After that you can call methods on the object.

Almost all objects inherit an according 
`-(instancetype)init` or `-(instancetype)initWith...` method you can use. If there is no `init` method given, then there is another way to do it right and the moment to start reading again :).

#### With Interface Builder

By typing `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` in front of a declaration you just give a hint for Xcodes Interface Builder where to hook up and apply onto (associate) the placed object in (nib,xib,storyboard) with its object ID in the XML scheme to a reference in code.

So after you connected your code and the object in IB you can avoid allocation and init process for that particular object. Be aware that calling methods on objects that are not instanced yet is not working. Which is why you code in `- (void)windowDidLoad`, -`(void)viewDidLoad` or `-(void)awakeFromNib` because those are the methods that get called after "IB" has done its job for you.